# Problem during logging in to Ubuntu

Tags: login, screen

I have completed dual boot of ubuntu with windows 10 successfully. But most of the time when i go for ubuntu boot option after entering my ubuntu login password, it will not start.
It will be showing blank screen with default ubuntu color screen

Answer (score 0):

1.press ctrl+alt+f3  then login using your credentials

3.create temp directory to copy your files $sudo mkdir /temporary

2.copy your all necessary files in /home folder  by hitting $ sudo cp /home /temporary

3.then make /home folder empty by hitting $sudo rm -rf ~*

4. $sudo init 6